# Clarifai PHP/GRPC - Code 14: failed to connect to all addresses

Tags: php, laravel, grpc, clarifai

So, I'm having this issue:

```
response: null
status: {
    code: 14 
    details: failed to connect to all addresses
}
```

I tried everything that I can think of, but nothing works and I'm out of ideas. Can someone help me? Thanks!

This is the code, like the exemple:

```
        $image = new Image([
            'base64' => file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $fileData['path'] . $fileData['name']),
        ]);

        $data = new Data([
            'image' => $image
        ]);

        $input = new Input([
            'data' => $data
        ]);

        $request = new PostModelOutputsRequest([
            'user_app_id' => $this->userDataObject, // This is defined above
            'model_id' => 'aaa03c23b3724a16a56b629203edc62c',  // This is the ID of the publicly available General model.
            'inputs' => [$input]
        ]);

        [$response, $status] = $this->client->PostModelOutputs(
            $request,
            $this->metadata
        )->wait();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloisa,

This is most likely to LetsEncrypt SSL certificate expiring.

- What operating system are you using?
- gRPC is planning on fixing the issue on the next release
- At the moment, you can attempt this workaround: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/27532#issuecomment-934006042
- You can also use simple REST calls until the gRPC implementation is fixed

Let me know if that helped!

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply
I'm using Ubuntu and the project it's in Laravel. So, this link was very helpful and I solved the problem goin to "vendor/grpc/grpc/etc/roots.pem" and pasting the new certificate on the GitHub comment (https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/etc/roots.pem)

Comment: New release 1.41.1 of gRPC Core fixes it https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/27539