# Firestore with PHP - Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\[DeadlineExceededException|ServiceException]

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, grpc

I'm running a PHP project with theses dependencies :

```json
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^3.9.2",
        "php": "^8.0.0",
        "slim/psr7": "^1.5",
        "google/cloud-firestore": "^1.20",
        "grpc/grpc": "^1.42",
        "google/cloud": "^0.175.0"
    }
}
```

I wan't to fetch data from a firestore database.

my php code :

```php
<?php
session_start();

require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'vendor' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'autoload.php';

$conf = [
    "keyFilePath" => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'src' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'conf' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'myfile.json'
];

use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;

$db = new FirestoreClient($conf);
$user = $db->collection("users")->where('email', '=', "an-email")->documents();
```

I've tried many tutorials and the official doc but i've theses errors randomely.
In many cases (80%) :

```
Type: Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException
Code: 14
Message: { "message": "failed to connect to all addresses", "code": 14, "status": "UNAVAILABLE", "details": [] }
File: /users/home/arnoux23u/www/charlemiapp/charlemiapp-auth/vendor/google/cloud/Core/src/GrpcRequestWrapper.php
Line: 257
```

and in some other cases :

```
Type: Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\DeadlineExceededException
Code: 4
Message: { "message": "Deadline Exceeded", "code": 4, "status": "DEADLINE_EXCEEDED", "details": [] }
File: /users/home/arnoux23u/www/charlemiapp/charlemiapp-auth/vendor/google/cloud/Core/src/GrpcRequestWrapper.php
Line: 257
```

I don't know what's the problem. The app is running fine on NodeJS.

I precise that I'm not the owner of the machine which host the app. The webmaster has installed grpc extension (1.43.0).

Comment: Hi @guillaumearnx, Could you please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69467718/clarifai-php-grpc-code-14-failed-to-connect-to-all-addresses) and see if it helps.

Comment: Hello. the server on which I make my request has a valid ssl certificate, moreover I use version 1..42,  it does not seem to be that ... 
Thank's

Comment: is the network connection stable? It looks like some network issues.

Comment: yes very stable. it's an university network served by renater. but when i perform the request, it takes between 30 seconds and 5 minutes before i get the error.

Comment: Did you follow and installed GRPC properly with this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc)?

Comment: Idk, i've just ask to the webmaster of the university if he can install grpc extension

Comment: Please try to install and follow the steps properly and give us a feedback on the result.

Comment: unfortunately it is not possible. i've no permissions